# How to read multiple integers on same line in bash?

Tags: bash, sh

```
declare -A a
for((i=0;i<2;i++))
for((j=0;j<5;j++))
read a[$i,$j]
```

I want to take  the  inputs on same line , but  this input

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 5
```

is not  doing the work , I have to take all 10 integers on different line .

Can I read  multiple  variables on same line in Bash  (if all are integers).

Comment: What do you mean "is doing the work"? Do you want to pass the numbers in a single line, or one number per line?

Comment: `sh` or `bash`? They're two different shells, and not mutually compatible (for example, the answer you have from that other guy works only with bash, not sh -- that's true for *any* answer that involves arrays, because `sh` doesn't guarantee any support for arrays at all).

Comment: To read integers into an array from a file: `arr=($(< arr.txt))`

Comment: `bash` doesn't have nested arrays. `a[$i][$j]` is not a valid name, regardless of the values of `i` or `j`.

Comment: @ Charles , I mean to say that work in both sh & bash , if a command works in sh , it will also work in bash

Comment: @Cheapner & @ Tom , I have updated the question , sorry for the Mistake

Comment: Also there is no 2d arrays in Bash

Comment: And for POSIX shell, there are no arrays at all (except the single `$@`, holding the positional parameters).

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL : In addition, your `for` loop, as posted, would be incorrect in both bash and POSIX shell, sind POSIX does not have arithmetic loops, and in bash, the `do` is missing. You find the correct syntax of a `for` loop which works in both shells [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04). I wonder where you got the syntax from, which you used in your posting.

Comment: @user1934428 , I do use " do & done" , but this also works fine in Bash .

Comment: Then, please update your question. It does not make sense to post syntactic incorrect code, if you already know the correct syntax. Also, you asked for a solution which works in both bash and POSIX, and this reduces your choices considerably.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-a` to put multiple fields into an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter some numbers:"
read -ra myarray
echo "There were ${#myarray[@]} numbers and index 4 was ${myarray[4]}"
```

If you enter `4 8 15 16 23 42` the output is:

```
There were 6 numbers and index 4 was 23
```

Comment: The question was about numbers on separate lines, but that wasn't clear before the edit.

Comment: What if I want to take  multiple integers on same line or input a 2d array

Comment: If you want to take multiple integers on the same line, you can use the example from this answer...

Comment: I have updated the question , my main question ia to take input of multiple variables on same line.

Comment: This answer shows how to take multiple variables on the same line. Please try it and see. It takes a **single** line with e.g. `4 8 15 16 23 42` (again, all on one line,  **not** on multiple lines). It then shows how to access the individual numbers from that single line.

Comment: Yes I got your point  , but I have to access it using array , but if there are two variable a and b ,  is there any way to do so ?

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL : There are no arrays in POSIX shell. You can't use a feature which is not there. The best you can do is do use `set --` to assign to the single array holding the positional parameters, but I don't see how this would help you here. Don't use a programming language which is not suitable for the task you are going to do.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is we cannot do it, as there is no provision of 2d array in Bash.

Input :

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 5
```

The following code will take the desired input as string array(whole line as a single input) and convert the individual string  to an array (which is a cubersome task as there are multiple integers in a string)
assuming the array dimension is 2x5 and then it prints the 2d array :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A b #Associative Array
for((i=0;i<2;i++))do
read a[$i]
done
for((i=0;i<2;i++))do
array=(${a[$i]}) # spliting the string into array
for((j=0;j<5;j++))do
b[$i,$j]=${array[$j]}
done
done
for((i=0;i<2;i++))do
for((j=0;j<5;j++))do
printf "${b[$i,$j]} "
done
echo
done
```

Hence we can conclude it is better to take input in multiple lines or else we have to follow these steps.